# Fixing the position of elements in Visual Studio XAML GUI

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to learn how to work in Visual Studio 2013 (WPF Application) with making a simple XAML GUI. Inside GRID I was using some basic elements like TextBlock, TreeView, ListView, etc...
Now here appears my problem. At the beggining I have made my "workspace" on resolution 350*525. I was draging the elements around that workspace, to place them in a perfect spot & order. Everything fits in that window as you can see on my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnZzU.png

But when I am trying to resize my window, everything is messed up like that: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvCXj.png
How I am able to fix it? I want that everything fits with window no matter how much you resize it, text should stay inside border.

I hope you guys understand my question and that someone is able to help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should consider using relative positions instead (such as placing elements inside containers like a Grid with row/column definitions). This will allow your application to handle resizing better. Or, you could just fix the width of the window.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525%28v=vs.90%29.aspx use content based Designing with row and columns so whenever sizing of window change automatically it will resize your controls. Rowdefination Height=Auto and columnDefination width=Auto so automatically change your size according to conrols

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Comment: @Dhru'soni

I am working inside GRID and I made some Grid and Rowdefinitions at the beginning before starting to drag elements around. I am not sure I understood you propperly so can you please explain me a little more in a simply way how to change it? And here is a printscreen of my layout and a little bit of code: http://i.imgur.com/hodinlm.png

Comment: @MikeEason
I am working inside GRID and I made some Grid and Rowdefinitions at the beginning before starting to drag elements around. I am not sure I understood you propperly so can you please explain me a little more in a simply way how to change it? And here is a printscreen of my layout and a little bit of code: http://i.imgur.com/hodinlm.png

Comment: @HC1122 put your code here not image xaml code so i can do it by my self Thank You

Comment: You will find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=denx2GJSyy8) useful.

Comment: @Dhru'soni Is there any possibility that I can send you my code via PM or Mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Xaml Gui" FontSize="25"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Try With this"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TreeView/>
            <TreeView/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBox Height="50" Width="100"/>
            <ListBox Height="50" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Put Your things here" FontSize="25"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Try it now " FontSize="25"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hm I wonder something. If I put my text inside that code, does every element gets bigger, or it just make the withe space around?

Comment: only which u change that will bigger @HC1122

Comment: Okay, got that now. But I wonder, how make more blank space between those two TreeViews, like I had on: http://i.imgur.com/PnPFlw1.png. 
Now everything is sticked together without free space.

Comment: Well I think Margin="5" makes 5px border around whole TreeVeiw, but I want it just on Bottom of first one :/
And sorry to bother you with my problems.

Comment: I hope you understend what I want to do.

Comment: @HC1122 you want just space between treeview ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Like 5px between upper and lower one.

Comment: try with margin=5 it will work it leave space between two treeview @HC1122

Comment: It is not that I want. I am really sorry to bother you, maybe my english is bad, and I am also bad at explaining so I made these print screen and I hope you Will be able to understand me now.

http://i.imgur.com/qwu3Rco.png

Comment: @HC1122    <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="50" Width="50"/>
            <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,5,0" Height="50" Width="50"/>

Comment: Omg, you are awesome!!!!! Thanks a lot buddy!

One LAST question I hope:

When I put a lot of text in that last one TextBlock it is going out of window.
Before I was using TextWrapping="Wrap" to manage it inside the box, but this is not working anymore. Any ideas of fixing it?

THANKS!

Comment: Or is the only way to make <LineBreak/> where it is going out of window?

Comment: Nevermind, solved it by myself!
Thanks a lot I appreciate your help.